# pentaho report designer : extract 'month' from format date in Capital Letter

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

The date column in my BD table is in date format like `2019-06-01`.
To show this on the report, I used

```
$(date_n, date, MMMM)
```

to get the month in letters, `'june'` for `'2019-06-01'`.
Now I want to make it in Capital letter,I know there's an option `UPPER()` on formula. But since this is a variable, don't have an idea how to formulate it.
I tried `UPPER(date_n,date,MMMM)`, and it says syntax error.

It would be really nice if someone can share his/her idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
UPPER( $(date_n, date, MMMM) )
```

Comment: it says it's syntax error. I did it on data-format, is it correct?

Comment: no, that should be the actual value of the field. Use a formula to create a new field based on the query value.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I still don't understand, what do you mean by "create a new field based on the query value" ? With my query, I get date_n in date format, what am I supposed to do on open formula?

Comment: on the RHS panel, under Data, you have the fields coming from your query, and also other options. One of them is formula. You create a new formula, put that formula there, and it gives you a new field you can drag to the canvas. See the Pentaho Report Designer documentation or training for examples of how to do that.

Comment: I created a new formula =UPPER($(date_n, date, MMMM)), syntax error. I tried with =UPPER("$(date_n, date, MMMM)"), this one has no syntax error, just gives     
$(MOIS_N, DATE, MMMM) as result. So I think we need quotes to use UPPER function, but then it doesn't consider it as variable.
You really tried to explain, thanks for it, but I tried all you said and it doesn't resolve the prob. Wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: try semi-colon instead of comma. I don't recall the syntax by heart, tbh, and it's been a while since I last used pentaho report designer.

Comment: I actually tried =UPPER(TEXT([date_n];"MMM")) and it finally works!! thanks for all your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the prob. Just in case someone has the same issue:

```
=UPPER(TEXT([date_n];"MMM"))
```

If you don't use TEXT function, it will say it's syntax error.